# Group by source and by month

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping

I am trying to create a query that will allow me to report on how our customers found out about us (i.e via google, yell, word of mouth etc).

I have two tables:

```
Customer
  name
  CreatedDate
  SourceID

Sources
  SourceID
  SourceName
```

This query:

```
SELECT Customer.CreatedDate, Source.SourceName
FROM Customer INNER JOIN
Source ON Customer.SourceID = Source.SourceID
```

Gives me a list of all the sources by date that were logged:

```
2011-05-05 00:00:00:000  Word Of Mouth
2011-05-05 00:00:00:000  Word Of Mouth
2011-05-05 00:00:00:000  Word Of Mouth
2011-05-05 00:00:00:000  Walk In
2011-05-05 00:00:00:000  Yell.com
2011-05-05 00:00:00:000  Google Search
```

What I am trying to get is a list that I can import into a pie chart and a report:

```
January 2013
Word of Mouth: 15
Walk In: 5
Google Search: 6
Yell.com 5

February 2013
Word of Mouth: 11
Walk In: 0
Google Search: 8
Yell.com 3
```

But I am unsure how I can create this report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT [Month] = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, c.CreatedDate), 0),
  s.SourceName,
  c = COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Customer AS c
INNER JOIN dbo.Source AS s
ON c.SourceID = s.SourceID
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, c.CreatedDate), 0),
  s.SourceName
ORDER BY [Month], s.SourceName;
```

If you just want a specific month, then:

```
SELECT s.SourceName, c = COUNT(*)
FROM dbo.Customer AS c
INNER JOIN dbo.Source AS s
ON c.SourceID = s.SourceID
WHERE c.CreatedDate >= '20130101'
AND c.CreatedDate < '20130201'
GROUP BY s.SourceName
ORDER BY s.SourceName;
```

Comment: Your answer was exactly what I was trying to do (but totally wrong!) and cannot beleive you managed to type it as quickly as you did - almost instant.  I'm a .Net developer but my SQL is not that great (just basic knowledge - enough to get by and spent a good two hours on this in the time you spent 3 mins!!).  I am just working out how to replace Month (2013-03-01 00:00:00:000) with a Month Name and Year.  Thanks again.

Comment: Do that in .NET. There are all kinds of string formatting options there, and that's where you should be handling display-type issues.